# Why can't I get a CSS button with Icon and no image?

Tags: css, button

I try to make into my button a css icon and not with image, and here is my css button :

**Button :**

```
<div>
     <b>
         <asp:Button ID="bt_VaildID" runat="server" Text="Valider" OnClick="bt_VaildID_Click" ValidationGroup="auGoup" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="bt_Valider" />
    </b>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bt_Valider {
display: inline-block;
border: 2px solid #903E71;
color: #000000;
border-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
font-family: Verdana;
width: auto;
height: auto;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 6px 25px;
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #903E71, #903E71);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #903E71, #903E71); /* for safari */
background-color: #903E71;
float:right;
}

.bt_Valider:hover, .bt_Valider:after {
    border: 2px solid #903E71;
    color: #903E71;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #FFF, #FFF);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #FFF, #FFF); /* for safari */
    cursor:pointer;
    content: "\279C"; /* I found that with this i can make some icon */
}
```

This code gives me this result : [Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLMJT.png)

But I want to get it like this : [Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KEIf.png)

Comment: Have a look at this -> https://jsfiddle.net/t0znfvpw/

Comment: Does this output a `<button>` or an `<input>`...there's a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if this is your desired result.

be aware that with `content: "\279C";` you are using an unicode character, se more here http://tutorialzine.com/2014/12/you-dont-need-icons-here-are-100-unicode-symbols-that-you-can-use/

```css
.bt_Valider {
display: inline-block;
border: 2px solid #903E71;
color: #000000;
border-radius: 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
font-family: Verdana;
width: auto;
height: auto;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 6px 25px;
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #903E71, #903E71);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #903E71, #903E71); /* for safari */
background-color: #903E71;
/* float:right; */
}

.bt_Valider:hover, .bt_Valider:after {
    /* border: 2px solid #903E71; */
    color: #000000;
    cursor:pointer; background:transparent;
    content: "\279C"; /* I found that with this i can make some icon */
}
```

```html
<div>
     <b>
     <Button ID="bt_VaildID" runat="server" Text="Valider" OnClick="bt_VaildID_Click" ValidationGroup="auGoup" CausesValidation="true" Class="bt_Valider" >Valider</Button>
    </b>
</div>
```